# Мигающая рамка на чистом javascript

Tags: javascript

дайте пожалуйста код мигающей рамки на чистоом javascript . нигде не могу найти.

Comment: что значит мигающая рамка. и причем тут javascript?

Comment: может бордер сделать мегающим

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if (document.getElementById("myborder").className == "noact") {
    document.getElementById("myborder").className = "active";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myborder").className = "noact" 
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#myborder {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.active {
  border:5px solid red;
}

.noact {
  border:5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="myborder" class="active"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1 - **Javascript**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("b-border")[0].style.borderColor = "gray";
  }, 1000);
}, 500);

setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("b-border")[0].style.borderColor = "green";
}, 1000);
```

```css
.b-border {
  border: 5px solid gray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-border"></div>
```

Вариант 2 - **CSS**

```css
.b-border {
  border: 5px solid gray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation: animBlinkBorder 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animBlinkBorder {
  0% {
    border-color: gray;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: gray;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b-border"></div>
```